# How do I translate a meta tag?

Tags: views, 8, meta-tags

I want to translate the *title* meta tag added to views on a Drupal 8 site, but I didn't see any option in the *Translate View* section.

How can I translate meta tags?

Comment: Did you enable `metatag: views` module ?

Comment: yes.I added Meta tag for english section.When go to "Translate view " tab, i can see translation for all other views settings except for meta tag.

Comment: @salu Did you enable Configuration Translation module?

Comment: @IsmailCherri:Yes,i have already enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I've added a title metatag to the default Content view. Then went to translation page where I found the string to translate under Displays-> Page Display Settings-> Display Extenders-> Test Metatags

[image: Views translation interface]

Comment: Thank you...I just find out this from my views.Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

For **Meta tags** to work with views you will need to enable `Metatag` module and `Metatag: Views` submodule both part of the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module download.

You need to go to `Extend` from the admin menu and enable the 2 modules

[image]

Comment: I have followed all these steps.But issue with translation only.In views settings i didnt see any option to translate meta tag.